# guzzlehttp, get request heders sent by GuzzleHttp\Client

Tags: php, guzzle

How can I get headers sent by GuzzleHttp\Client()->get('URL')?
I can only get response headers, but not request. Help! thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can call the `getHeaders()` method of Request to get all the headers in a request, if you want to specifically check for a header you can use `hasHeader()`

```
use GuzzleHttp\Psr7;

$request = new Psr7\Request('GET', 'URL', ['Foo' => 'Bar']);

//Check for a header
if ($request->hasHeader('Foo')) {
  echo 'Yes.';
}

//Get all the headers  
foreach ($request->getHeaders() as $name => $values) {
    echo $name .': ' . implode(', ', $values) . "\r\n";
}
```

Comment: this will give me response headers, not request headers which Guzzle Client has sent

Comment: This will give you request headers, I'm not sure what you're trying to acheive, in this case though, you're passing the header 'Foo' => 'Bar' in your request, and you check if the request has this header using the hasHeader() method. more details here :- http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/latest/psr7.html#accessing-headers